# getting Json data from database with ajax -post() is different(become double ) everytime

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getReady(){
        $('.selectpicker').empty(); //clear the select
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST", 
                contentType : "application/json", 
                url : "/btlocationServer/GetBeaconInfo", 
                dataType : 'json',
                cache:false,
                success : function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        $('.selectpicker').append("<option >"+item.name+"--"+item.address+"</option>");   //append data to option of select
                        console.log(item.name+"--"+item.address);//log data
                    });
                    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

it's the first time when I start the server

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFeZl.png)

the second time I refresh the page:

[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMop5.png)

and everytime I refresh the page ,data will become double.

so how can I deal with it

Comment: I think it's because of this:  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')

Comment: it's not , if I delete  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh') ,problem still here,and the select became unnormal